# Swift NSTextField stringValue not displaying set value

Tags: swift, macos

Hello Sultans of Swift!

I am new to Swift although I have used C, C++ and C# a lot. I have come upon a situation that is really puzzling me. I'm going to post a code snippet here:

```
@IBAction func myFunc(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let dirPicker: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    dirPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    dirPicker.canChooseFiles = true
    dirPicker.canChooseDirectories = false
    dirPicker.runModal()

    let selection = dirPicker.URL

    if(selection != nil)
    {
        do
        {
            print(selection)
            let mp3File = try MP3File(path: (selection?.path)!)
            let title = mp3File.getTitle()

            // This prints OK
            print("Title:\t\(mp3File.getTitle())")

            // This prints OK too
            print("Title:\t\(title)")

            print("Artist:\t\(mp3File.getArtist())")
            print("Album:\t\(mp3File.getAlbum())")
            print("Lyrics:\n\(mp3File.getLyrics())")

            fileName.stringValue = (selection?.path)!

            // This sets the label songTitle to an empty space and I can't see why.
            // If I initialise title to:
            //     let title = "STRING CONSTANT"
            // ...instead of 
            //     let title = mp3File.getTitle()
            // ...then it does actually set the correct text on the label songTitle.
            // In both cases, printing to the console works fine! Its just setting 
            // the text on the label that is eluding me!
            songTitle.stringValue = title
        }
        catch ID3EditErrors.FileDoesNotExist
        {
            print("Error: File Does Not Exist")
        }
        catch ID3EditErrors.NotAnMP3
        {
            print("Error: Not an MP3")
        }
        catch let e
        {
            print(e)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to set the text in a label by setting its stringValue property to a variable it just displays empty space, yet I can actually print the variable to the console just fine. The variable is set as the return value of a function. Now if I instead set the variable explicitly to a string constant then it works. So this will be perhaps related to the uncertainty of the return value of the function, but I know it contains the text because I can print it to the console.

Can anyone spot what on earth is happening here?

Thanks

EDIT: I just fixed the comments in the code to refer to songTitle instead of fileName - sorry for the confusion. This is about setting songTitle.stringValue = title

EDIT: This is the definition of songTitle:

```
@IBOutlet weak var fileName: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var songTitle: NSTextField!
```

Note that setting the stringValue property of these does actually work so long as I am not using the a variable that is assigned the return value of mp3File.getTitle(). Note also that mp3File.getTitle() does return a value and I can print it to the console OK.

Comment: What do you get with `debugPrint(title)` ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in answering - I was away. Here are 3 debug statements that I added:

Comment: debugPrint("DEBUG TEXT")
debugPrint(title)
debugPrint(songTitle.stringValue)

Comment: **"\0I Ran\0"**

Comment: **"\0I Ran\0"**

Comment: Above is the output of the debug print statements in order. It is curious to see that reading back from stringValue actually does give the correct text but it doesn't display it. If I change the declaration of title to let title = "TEXT CONSTANT" then it does display TEXT CONSTANT. It's really odd...

Comment: Seems you are mis-implementing your `MP3File.getTitle()`. It has NUL characters (U+0000) at both ends. You may need to re-implement `MP3File.getTitle()` and remove those NUL characters.

Comment: Ohhh you are right too!! Thats not my function - its from a library but well spotted

Comment: For a quick fix, you can use `let title = mp3File.getTitle().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\0"))`. You'd better write a `patch` extension for the library.

Comment: Cheers - can you post your comments as an answer so that I can mark it as answered by you? Thanks again

Comment: OK, I'll rearrange my comments as an answer.

Comment: Just one thing, CharacterSet isn't recognised, at least in my install of Xcode v7.3.1. There is an NSCharacterSet - do I need to import some lib to use it? If I use NSCharacterSet instead the compiler complains that string has no member trimmingCharacters

Comment: I think that comes with swift 3 and I need to upgrade to Xcode 8...

Comment: Sorry, I could not find out that you are using Swift 2. You can use `NSCharacterSet` and may need to use methods as in Swift 2 naming. I'll add Swift 2 code to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a String value which is `print`ed fine:

```
print(title) //->I Ran
```

But cannot be processed well:

```
songTitle.stringValue = title //->`songTitle` shows nothing!!!
```

(Of course, you have confirmed that `songTitle` is fine by assigning constant string to it.)

One possible reason may be existing some control characters in the String.

You can use `debugPrint` to reveal such cases:

```
debugPrint(title) //->"\0I Ran\0"
```

`debugPrint` uses String literal-like format to show control characters.

In this case, you have NUL characters (U+0000) at both ends.

So, one quick fix is trimming them at each time you get such strings:

**Swift 2**:

```
let title = mp3File.getTitle().stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\0"))
```

**Swift 3**:

```
let title = mp3File.getTitle().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\0"))
```

---

Or you can write an extension, if you cannot touch the original source of the library:

**Swift 2**:

```
extension MP3File {
    var title: String {
        return self.getTitle().stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\0"))
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**:

```
extension MP3File {
    var title: String {
        return self.getTitle().trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\0"))
    }
}
```

(Assuming `MP3File` does not have a property named `title`.)

and use it as:

```
let title = mp3File.title
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer @OOPer

Comment: Great answer - very comprehensive!